# jQuery .getJSON() not working in my Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, getjson

I'm newbie to jQuery, and already properly included jQuery library to my Wordpress, however, can't seem to execute jQuery call in my Wordpress, see no results coming back. Here are snippets of my code:

---

```
/* In my html, initiate call when selecting a different member id */
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select_member_id").change(function() {
        $.getJSON("<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/get_member_info.php",    {"member_id" : $(this).val()}, function(jMember,status) {
            member = JSON.parse (jMember);
            $("#member_firstname").text(member.first_name);
        });
        });
         });
</script>
```

---

```
/* In get_member_info.php suppose to return a JSON result */
    <?php
      include("member_roster.php"); // this is just an array file
      $member_id = $_GET["member_id"];
      echo "{" . '"'.'first_name'.'"' . " : " . $member_roster[$member_id] ["first_name"] . "}";
    ?>
```

---

Please advise me what I'm doing wrong...THANKS A LOT GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.getJSON` the data is already parsed so don't call `JSON.parse`.

```
$.getJSON("<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/get_member_info.php",    {"member_id" : $(this).val()}, function(member,status) {
    $("#member_firstname").text(member.first_name);
});
```

Also building json by hand is a bad idea, you should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode(array('first_name' => $member_roster[$member_id] ["first_name"] ));
```

Comment: And what if you parse it again anyway ? do it become unParsed or so ?

Comment: Thank you so much Musa! Just saved my day! Thx Thx!!